# Accessing data in variables in class Python 3

Tags: python, class, object

I am using Python 3.5 and wish to do something like this
I have created a class which has variables `Bitcoin`, `Monero` , 'Etherum' ,etc with various integer values ,I wish to extract them

```
var1="Bitcoin"

value=classobj.var1 // there is a class which has a variable called Bitcoin and its value is 10 I wish to get its value using classobject.Bitcoin but the variable called var is Dynamic
print (value)
```

How do I achieve the same ?

**EDIT**

I know it is possible using switch statement but I am looking for other ways

Comment: Is there a reason `classobj` is a class instance with attributes like "Bitcoin", instead of a dict with elements like "Bitcoin"?

Comment: Yeah I m using Django so that class is  a model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost always a bad idea—and you really should explain why your design looks like this, because it's probably a bad design.

But "almost always" isn't "always", so Python has a way to do this:

```
getattr(classobj, var)
```

Comment: Should `var` be `'var'` or is `isinstance(var, str)` `True`? (or do I not understand how `getattr` works)

Comment: `var` should be the variable `var`, not the string `'var'`. But yes, `isinstance(var, str)` should be true—as it is in the OP's question. If the value of `var` is a string, `'Bitcoin'`, then `getattr(classobj, var)` is the same as `getattr(classobj, 'Bitcoin')`, which is the same as `classobj.Bitcoin`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).